# Correct? "We make no prescriptions ..."

Tags: meaning, word-usage, terminology

Can I use `"We make no prescriptions about ..."`? This [dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/prescription?s=t) doesn't give any definition of the word `"prescription"` apart from Medical or Legal jargon.

Comment: What are you trying to say? Without more context, you could mean "predictions" or "guarantees" or any of a number of things.

Comment: I don't see any medical jargon in the definition...

Comment: Try [this dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/prescription?q=prescription)

Comment: My gut feeling says you mean “presumptions”.

Comment: In fact, if you had followed the links in your dictionary's definition 2 or 3 they would have led you to *prescribe*, defined as "1. to lay down, in writing or otherwise, as a rule or a course of action to be followed; appoint, ordain, or enjoin", as well as intransitive definitions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not using a good enough dictionary. [Oxford dictionaries online](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/prescription?q=prescription) gives:

> **2a** recommendation that is authoritatively put forward: *effective prescriptions for sustaining rural communities*.

So if that is what you mean by "prescription," your sentence is fine.

Comment: In fact, if OP had followed the link in his dictionary's definition 3, "that which is prescribed", it would have led him to *prescribe*, defined as "1. to lay down, in writing or otherwise, as a rule or a course of action to be followed; appoint, ordain, or enjoin."

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to say with such limited context ("We make no prescriptions about ..." what?) but the most general meaning is:

*The action or an act of prescribing or setting down something beforehand, esp. as a rule, law, etc.; a thing which is prescribed or set down; written or explicit direction or injunction.*

OED

This would mean that in your sentence, "we are not setting any terms about (whatever) before (whatever)"